# What is the "spirit of wisdom" in Deuteronomy 34:9?

Tags: referent-identification, deuteronomy, spirit

> 9 And Joshua son of Nun is full of **the spirit of wisdom**, for Moses had laid his hands upon him, and the sons of Israel hearken unto him, and do as Jehovah commanded Moses. (Deuteronomy 34:9 YLT)

What is the "spirit of wisdom"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more information about the background of the phrase, "Spirit of Wisdom" see the appendix below.

Thus, it appears that this idea anticipates the "gifts of the Spirit" in the NT.  Note the comments of Ellicott on Ex 28:3.

> **Whom I have filled with the spirit of wisdom**.—Few passages in the Bible are more antagonistic than this to the general current of modern
> thought. God speaks of Himself as having infused His Spirit into the
> hearts of men, in order to enable them to produce satisfactory
> priestly garments.

Similarly, the Cambridge commentary offers these remarks in the same passage:

> **the spirit of wisdom** i.e. an impulse and activity, instinct with wisdom (i.e., here, artistic skill): cf. Deuteronomy 34:9 (P), Isaiah
> 11:2; Isaiah 28:6; and (in a bad sense) Isaiah 19:14; Isaiah 29:10,
> Hosea 4:12. Comp. on Exodus 31:3.

**APPENDIX - "Spirit of Wisdom"**

The phrase "Spirit of Wisdom" occurs a number of places in the OT and always suggesting a divine impartation of supernatural ability:

- Ex 28:3 - You shall speak to all the skillful people whom I have endowed with the **spirit of wisdom**, that they make Aaron’s garments to consecrate him, that he may serve as priest to Me.
- Ex 31:3 - And I have filled him with the **Spirit of God in wisdom**, in understanding, in knowledge, and in all kinds of craftsmanship [Compare V6]
- Ex 35:31 - And He has filled him with the **Spirit of God, in wisdom**, in understanding, in knowledge, and in all craftsmanship; [compare V35, 36:1, 2
- Deut 34:9 - Now Joshua the son of Nun was filled with the **spirit of wisdom**, because Moses had laid his hands on him; and the sons of Israel listened to him and did as the LORD had commanded Moses.
- Isa 11:2 - And the Spirit of the LORD shall rest upon him, the **Spirit of wisdom** and understanding, the Spirit of counsel and might, the Spirit of knowledge and the fear of the LORD.  For more information about this passage, see my answer to this question --> [How many spirits are in view in Isaiah 11:2?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/how-many-spirits-are-in-view-in-isaiah-112/59523#59523)
- Eph 1:17 - that the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of glory, may give you the **Spirit of wisdom** and of revelation in the knowledge of him,

Thus, the "Spirit" of Wisdom" is a technical phrase denoting a special supernatural gift or ability in something.