# What is this ‘spirit of glory’ Peter refers to? 1Pet 4:14

Tags: spirit, 1-peter

> If you are insulted for the name of Christ, you are blessed, because the Spirit of glory, and of God, rests upon you. 1Pet 4:14

Does Peter distinguish the spirit of glory from God as if they are somehow separate? What is he expressing here?

Answer (score 1):

The grammar in 1 Peter 4:14 demands a translation that contains:

- "... because of the spirit of glory and of God", ie, one spirit which is both of glory and of God.

That is, there are not two entities in view - there is one spirit with two descriptions:

- the spirit of glory, and
- the same spirit of God

Thus, we translate that we have ONE spirit who is both of glory and of God.  This is reinforced several times in the bible where the spirit is described with numerous titles, but there is only one spirit - see appendix below taken from [How many spirits are in view in Isaiah 11:2?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/how-many-spirits-are-in-view-in-isaiah-112/59523#59523)

**APPENDIX - Isa 11:2, 3**

This marvelous passage in Isa 11:1-3 is actually part of an inverse chiasm which we will not go into here.  Suffice to say that it appears to be the basis for several NT passages about the Holy Spirit.  But before quoting them I note that Isa 11:2 lists seven characteristics of the Holy Spirit:

1. Spirit of the LORD
2. Spirit of wisdom
3. Spirit of understanding
4. Spirit of counsel
5. Spirit of strength
6. Spirit of knowledge
7. Spirit of fear of the LORD

Let us note the following from the NT:

- 1 Cor 12:9 - and to a different one faith by the **same Spirit**, and to another gifts of healing by the **one Spirit**,
- 1 Cor 12:13 - For in **one Spirit** we were all baptized into one body, whether Jews or Greeks, slave or free, and we were all given one Spirit to drink.
- Eph 2:18 - For through Him we both have access to the Father by **one Spirit**.
- Eph 4:4 - There is one body and **one Spirit**, just as you were called to one hope when you were called;

There appears a more specific reference in Rev 4:5 -

> From the throne came flashes of lightning, and rumblings, and peals of
> thunder. Before the throne burned seven torches of fire. These are the
> sevenfold Spirit of God.